# What is the probability that 2 people get the same result in a binomial simulation?

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, simulation

If I'm using a simulator for Bernoulli distributions, and I'm doing 10 trials with a probability of 0.25, assuming it's completely random, what are the chances that I'm going to get the same exact result as someone else that repeats the exact same experiment?

I've been at a loss at to how to answer this because not every X value has the same likelihood of happening so multiplying probabilities doesn't seem feasible. Adding 10 + 10 trials doesn't seem to work either. I could try to add both distributions but I don't know if that will help either. I looked up the addition of binomial distributions and found this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution

but that just leaves me more confused than ever.

Comment: What does "same exact result" mean?  Is it enough to say you got the same number of successes or do you need the sequence of test results to match term by term?

Comment: The same number of successes.

Comment: And where is the difficulty? What is the probablility that both get no successes? What is the probability that both get exactly one success? And so on. Then just add.

Comment: What if we needed the sequence of test results to match?

Comment: Then compute the probability that they match on a single test and raise that to the tenth power.

Comment: Is there a less tedious way, like avoiding all of the manual calculations?

Comment: The same sequence version is not tedious at all, and the other is easily programmed (granted, it's a bit tedious if you are doing it with pencil and paper).  In any case, I doubt there is a practical short cut.

Comment: Since you're already simulating, you could do person A's simulation 1,000,000 times and person B's simulation 1,000,000 times and let the program find the proportion of times A and B match (by whatever definition of matching you choose). You could expect two or three decimal places of accuracy. For example, in R: `mean(rbinom(10^6, 10, 1/4)==rbinom(10^6, 10, 1/4))` returns
$0.205\pm 0.0008.$ Whereas, the exact result is `sum(dbinom(0:10,10,1/4)^2)`, returning $0.2053272.$